# Trying to rename cer to pem

Tags: certificate, pem

I am trying to rename file from cer to pem because I am trying to integrate Zscaler with our Azure AD and the people on the Zscaler side specifically asked for the pem extension in the file name.

I tried to just F2 on the filename and change it to Example.pem, but it just changes the filename to Example.pem.cer.

I also tried to download Git with VS Code and use openSSL, but I am very green with that stuff and couldn't get it to work with what I was finding on other questions like this. Kept getting error saying "Unknown Parameters"

I am on Windows 11 if that helps.

Comment: A pem file is just a different encoding of the same data. Pem files can be opened in a text editor and you see a lot of base64 data. For beginners it is often easier to use a GUI tool like keystoreexplorer where you open/import the cer file and then export it as pem.

Comment: That seemed to work. If it did work, would I be able to open the file using Crypto Shell Extensions like I can with a cer file, or is it just something I can open with Notepad?

Comment: Files containing a PEM certificate (content like `---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE --- ...`)  can be opened using Crypto Shell Extension, but only if you rename the file extension to `.cer` (weird but the pem extension is usually not registered with Crypto Shell Extension).